# Service Fabric Service Fails to Start with TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, .net, azure-service-fabric

We have a Service Fabric application with several actors and services. The actors & services successfully deploy and run on most of the development machines. On a few of the development machines, however, one of the services shows in an error status for no apparent reason.

In Service Fabric Explorer, the error icon shows on the Cluster all the way down to the partition. However, the node did not show that it was in an error state. Several minutes of waiting later, the node did show a warning icon and the following error message:

> Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.RA', Property='ReplicaOpenStatus',
>   HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false. Replica had
>   multiple failures during open. Error =System.TypeLoadException
>   (-2146233054) Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.ReliableStateManagerImpl' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.ReliableStateManager.get_Impl()    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.ReliableStateManager.Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.IStateProviderReplica.Initialize(StatefulServiceInitializationParameters
>   initializationParameters)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatefulServiceBase.System.Fabric.IStatefulServiceReplica.Initialize(StatefulServiceInitializationParameters
>   initializationParameters)    at
>   System.Fabric.ServiceFactoryBroker.CreateHelper[TFactory,TReturnValue](IntPtr
>   nativeServiceType, IntPtr nativeServiceName, UInt32
>   initializationDataLength, IntPtr nativeInitializationData, Guid
>   partitionId, Func`3 creationFunc, Action`2 initializationFunc,
>   ServiceInitializationParameters initializationParameters)

I set breakpoints and found that every expected line of program.cs executes and it eventually gets to the Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite). But not a single line of the failing service's code gets hit.

The service at issue is Stateful and shares an assembly with a Stateless Actor. I don't tend to put two actors/services in one dll but a colleague did and it works for most of the team. Don't know if this is a potential issue.

Everyone on the team was running SDK 1.5 when this occurred on two dev machines. I upgraded to SDK 2.0 (but didn't change the assembly references in Nuget to use the 2.0 assemblies). Same problem.

I did a search for the assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl' and found it under [Program Files]\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code. It is version 5.0.135.9590.

My colleague, who has it working, has that same file as version 4.5.175.9590.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know the specifics, but I believe that once you've fully upgraded (latest SDK + latest nuget packages) the issue will go away.

Comment: That's probably our next course of action. Every version of the SF SDK is better than the last. I've been playing with 2.0 on a VM and it's wonderful.

Comment: Indeed, some great stuff in the new SDK! I guess my suggestion was that it's probably not worth digging into finding out what's going on here and just upgrade if possible. It'd be great if we could get an explanation though.

Comment: It would be good to know. That way, if it happens again I know how to troubleshoot it. The more of us that know the ins and outs of Service Fabric the better. :-)

Comment: charisk is right, update everything to the latest release and you'll be good to go. The 5.0 runtime is only compatible with the 2.0 SDK that was released with it. In future releases you can expect better backwards-compatibility.